# Pandora Stations Disappeared

Tags: pandora

All my **Pandora** stations (with the exception of a couple) have disappeared about two weeks ago. Since then, I was able to bring back a few of them, but not all.
In my **Activity** tab I could find some of the recent stations I listened to and by clicking on them they were brought back to my **Stations** list. But the activity list didn't go back far enough to list all the station.

I also tried to access my account from multiple devices, logged out and back in, remove all cookies from the browser, and so on.. with no luck.

I was not able to find anything regarding this issue and how to fix it. I'd like to know if anyone else has experienced something similar and if so, what could I do to bring them back.

### EDIT

I've also contacted Pandora support regarding this issue and heard nothing back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while Pandora got back to me and recovered all my stations, including the ones deleted many years back. They did not give me an answer as to what actually happened, only that they were all deleted.
Unfortunately I do not have a better explanation.